# Windows 10 IoT vs Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: windows-10, iot

Could anyone please explain how I can confirm if an OS is Windows 10 Enterprise or if it is Windows 10 IoT (Value and Entry.)

I used to think LTSB/CBB/CB (Long Term Service Branch/Current Branch for Business/Current Branch) was an indicator, but now I am unsure. Are the branch editions just an indicator of windows update frequency for all windows versions, or is it exclusive to IoT?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: If you have x86 hardware then you are not running Windows IoT

Comment: Windows 10 IoT Core is not a desktop operating system. I don’t understand what you’re asking about.

Comment: @Ramhound The hardware is x64 based.

Comment: Also, Microsoft says: “Windows 10 IoT Enterprise is a binary equivalent to Windows 10 Enterprise.”

Comment: @DanielB We are using Windows 10 IoT Value and Entry for our Panel PC's and Box PC's depending on the CPU. Are you suggesting that IoT is just a software pack? If that is the case, then I totally misunderstood what it was.

Comment: @user724296 x64 is an extension of the x86 architecture.  Typically viewing the properties of My PC indicates which version of Windows 10 your using

Comment: I’m not suggesting that IoT is a software pack. Windows 10 IoT Enterprise *is* Windows 10 Enterprise and nothing but. It’s a licensing model.

Comment: @DanielB You blew my mind a little bit. So, What is the main difference between Windows 10 IoT Enterprise and Windows 10 Enterprise? Nothing?